# Running instance of OpenSSH's sshd on OS X, but it won't accept valid user passwords

Tags: macos, openssh

I'm running a instance of OpenSSH's sshd on OS X (10.8.3), but it won't accept valid user passwords.  It simply responds, "Permission denied, please try again." I'm ssh'ing to localhost.  If I add my public key to .ssh/authorized_keys, I can connect without issue.

I assumed that OS X was preventing the application from accessing OS X's auth system (i.e. /etc/shadow?), so then tried running sshd under sudo, <strike>but ran into an issue of sshd immediately crashing upon a client connecting with this error on the server</strike> (**see update 2 below**):

> ssh_sandbox_child: ssandbox_init: dlopen(/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib, 261): image not found  [preauth]

Any help on either of these issues is appreciated.

In case it's worth noting: I am not trying to replace my existing sshd service on OS X, but simply want to run this one in parallel for something I'm testing.

**Update:** I forgot to mention that this same code and configuration works perfectly fine compiled and ran on an Ubuntu 12.10 system. On the linux box, I'm not running under sudo.

**Update 2:** I resolved the server's issue of running under sudo by setting `UsePrivilegeSeparation yes` in my sshd_config, but passwords are still not accepted.

Comment: Do you have `UsePAM yes` in your sshd_config?

Comment: `UsePAM yes` was not in config, but I tried adding, and same result. I forgot to mention that this exact same config and codebase work on a Linux machine. I'll update my question to further ellaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bart for pointing me in the right direction (OS X is expecting PAM).

As described [here](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-bugs/2003-September/000636.html), to build OpenSSH with PAM, one must configure to use via: `./configure --with-pam` before running `make`.

Adding `UsePAM yes` to sshd_config as Bart suggested is also needed.